# Can't have access to a variable using call in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm studying `Javascript` and learning how to use `call`. I created this script and I don't know why I can't have access to this variable `Time`.

```js
var MyObject;
(function(MyObject) {
  var Runner = (function() {
    function Runner(time) {
      this.time = time;
    }
    var myFunctionArray = [];
    Runner.prototype.execute = function() {
      myFunctionArray[0]();
    }

    Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
      var test = function() {
        return execute.call(this);
      }
      myFunctionArray.push(test);
    }
    return Runner;
  })();
  MyObject.Runner = Runner;
})(MyObject || (MyObject = {});

var myNewObj = new MyObject.Runner(1000); myNewObj.newTest('1', function() {
  console.log(this.time) //output: undefined
});
```

So how can I get time value inside `newTest` function?

Comment: I'm a little confused. In your `newTest` function, you are pushing `execute` to an array, but its not called. Also an alternate is to use `execute.bind(this)` instead of `function(){ execute.call(this) }`

Comment: The anonymous function's `this` refers to `window`. Try doing `function() { console.log(this.time); }.bind(this)`

Comment: @AndrewLi No. `this` is pointing to a temp function `test` as OP is using `.call(this)` inside `test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in `newTest` function

```js
Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
  var test = function() {
    return execute.call(this);
  }
  myFunctionArray.push(test);
}
```

Here `this` is pointing to `test` and not `Runner`. You will have to save context in a variable and then set it in call.

```js
Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
  var self = this;
  var test = function() {
    return execute.call(self);
  }
  myFunctionArray.push(test);
}
```

#### .call + self

```js
var MyObject;
(function(MyObject) {
  var Runner = (function() {
    function Runner(time) {
      this.time = time;
    }
    var myFunctionArray = [];
    Runner.prototype.execute = function() {
      myFunctionArray[0]();
    }

    Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
      var self = this;
      var test = function() {
        return execute.call(self);
      }
      myFunctionArray.push(test);
    }
    return Runner;
  })();
  MyObject.Runner = Runner;
})(MyObject || (MyObject = {}));

var myNewObj = new MyObject.Runner(1000);
myNewObj.newTest('1', function() {
  console.log(this, this.time) //output: undefined
});
myNewObj.execute()
```

#### .bind

As commented, you can even use `.bind`

```js
var MyObject;
(function(MyObject) {
  var Runner = (function() {
    function Runner(time) {
      this.time = time;
    }
    var myFunctionArray = [];
    Runner.prototype.execute = function() {
      myFunctionArray[0]();
    }

    Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
      myFunctionArray.push(execute.bind(this));
    }
    return Runner;
  })();
  MyObject.Runner = Runner;
})(MyObject || (MyObject = {}));

var myNewObj = new MyObject.Runner(1000);
myNewObj.newTest('1', function() {
  console.log(this, this.time) //output: undefined
});
myNewObj.execute()
```

Comment: Thank you! Working fine now!

Comment: Just a pointer, `(MyObject|| (MyObject= {})` should be `(MyObject || {})`

Answer (score 0):

When you declare your Runner function, you've actually declared a function that takes no arguments that then itself declares a function called Runner that takes one argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually In this code snippet :

```
Runner.prototype.newTest = function(index, execute) {
      var test = function() {
         return execute.call(this);
      }
      myFunctionArray.push(test);
   }
```

this will reference to test variable (as per constructor invocation pattern)
So, to pass right variable cache the value of this in another variable and then pass that to function.